# Reversing string in C

Tags: c, string

i try to build code that will reverse the string words like this:

```
input: Hello World!
output:olleH !dlroW
```

i can't use any pointers
The code i build is that,
There is a function that got the sentences list address (matrix with up to 20 lines) - table, number of the sentences that in the table and the number of the sentence that i want to change.

```
int changeCharOrder(char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH], int numOfSentences, int sentenceToChange) {
    int slen, slen2, slenrev, lastwordlen=0, c=0, i, q, f, start=0;
    char reversed[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]; // the reversed sentence will be here
    char oneword[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH];  // i tried to split the sentence to words and then reverse them
    reversed[0] = '\0';
    slen = strlen(table[sentenceToChange]);
    for (i = 0; i < slen; i++) { //for loop to looking for space or EOS
        while((table[sentenceToChange][i] != ' ') && (table[sentenceToChange][i] != '\0')) {
            oneword[c] = table[sentenceToChange][i]; // copy the word and save in oneword
            i++;
            c++;
        }

        oneword[i+1] = '\0';
        slen2 = strlen(oneword);
        slenrev = strlen(reversed);
        for(q = i+slen2-1; q > i; q--){ // here is the reversing code. it's not working well 
            reversed[q-1] = table[sentenceToChange][start];
            start++;
        }
        start++;
        lastwordlen = strlen(oneword);
        reversed[slen] = '\0';
        c = 0;
    }
    reversed[slen] = '\0';
    printf("%s",reversed);  
}
```

It's not working as it's should. i able to reverse only the first word.
Any advice? thanks

Comment: Please indent your code. How it is like now it's unreadable.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use your debugger - that will be much more useful in the long term than crowd-sourcing your debugging efforts.

Comment: change `oneword[i + 1] = '\0';` to `oneword[i] = '\0';` after while loop, as you are increased value of `i` in while loop.

Comment: i change the code and add some notes, i tried to use the debugger but i can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Himanshu, you right, one of the problem is that the reversed variable is become bigger and bigger after each loop

Comment: Why u r using `slen2=strlen(oneword);` for counting length. you already using variable `c` for counting.

Comment: change `for(q=i+slen2-1;q>i;q--)` to `for(q=c-1;q>=0;q--)`

Comment: yes, i will change that.

Comment: Himanshu, now it's reveresed the first word, the main problem is to add the second word after that with space between them. :-(

Comment: Space you can get by changing `"%s"` to `"%s "` in you `printf`

Comment: but i need to save everything inside another char string. '"Hello Word"-> "olleH droW" '

Comment: @Matan, if you tried to use a debugger, show your research and results in the question, it will help a lot helping you :).

Comment: I think you may be reverse its scope by examining the position of the word you're going back to write a word of upside-down.

Comment: The code now output: !dlrow╠╠╠╠╠╠ for "Hello World!".

Comment: I need to add somehow to 'reversed[q]' index the next word index, if "World!" starting in index number 6 in the original sentence it's should be start in index number 11 in the reversed index down to index 6.

Comment: Kind people keep fixing the indention, but the OP keeps rolling back to unreadable crap. So vote to close as "unclear what you are asking", since the code is unclear and not readable as it currently stands. Let the OP fix his indention himself now, and if he doesn't, tough luck.

Comment: Problem solved. thanks to BLUEPIXY and Himanshu, Thanks all for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
for (i=0; i<slen; i++) { //for loop to looking for space or EOS
    while((table[sentenceToChange][i]!=' ')&&(table[sentenceToChange][i]!='\0')) {
        oneword[c] = table[sentenceToChange][i]; // copy the word and save in oneword
        i++;
        c++;
    }

    oneword[i]='\0';
    c--;
    slen2=strlen(oneword);
    slenrev=strlen(reversed);
    for(q=c;c>=0;c--){  //you can remove `q=c` also 'for(;c>=0;c--)' will also work
        reversed[start]=oneword[c]; 
        start++;
    }
    reversed[start++]=' ';
    reversed[start]='\0';
    c=0;
}
printf("\n%s",reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){
    char sentence[] = "Hello World!";
    int i, word_top, word_end;
    for(i=0; sentence[i]; ++i){
        if(sentence[i] == ' ')
            continue;
        word_end = word_top = i;
        while(sentence[word_end] && sentence[word_end] != ' ')
            ++word_end;
        i = --word_end;//move back one
        while(word_end > word_top){
            //swap top and end
            char temp = sentence[word_top];
            sentence[word_top++] = sentence[word_end];
            sentence[word_end--] = temp;
        }
    }
    puts(sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is another in a similar vein

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH 30

int changeCharOrder(char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH], int sentenceToChange) {
    int i=0, j, k;
    char *sptr = table[sentenceToChange];     // make code more readable
    char reversed[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH];       // reversed words will be here
    strcpy (reversed, sptr);                  // copy source spaces and terminator
    while (sptr[i]) {                         // until end of string
        while (sptr[i] > 0 && sptr[i] <= ' ') // find first char
            i++;
        j = i;
        while (sptr[j] > ' ')                 // find end of word
            j++;
        k = j;                                // where word ended
        while (i < j)                         // reverse the word
            reversed[i++] = sptr [--k];
    }
    printf("%s\n%s\n\n", sptr, reversed);  
}

int main(void)
{
    char sents [3][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH] = 
            {"Hello World!", "Second sentence", " Three   words here   ."};
    changeCharOrder (sents, 0);
    changeCharOrder (sents, 1);
    changeCharOrder (sents, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Hello World!
olleH !dlroW

Second sentence
dnoceS ecnetnes

 Three   words here   .
 eerhT   sdrow ereh   .
```