# C program- change char order in sentence

Tags: c

I would love to get some help with a task that I have, and I can't seem to get it.
I need to write a function with that changes char order in a sentence. example: 
"hello world " will turn into: "olleh dlrow".
this is the function prototype I was given:

```
int changeCharOrderInSentence(char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH], int numOfSentences, int sentenceToChange)
```

I can't use pointers, static var or anything.
after every word there is a space, what do I do with that ? 
and the function need to return a value.. what it is ? I don't get it because the function just changes the order of chars.
this is what I wrote:

```
  int changeCharOrderInSentence(char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH], int numOfSentences, int sentenceToChange)
{
    int i,j,lensentence;
    char temp;
    lensentence=strlen(table[sentenceToChange]);
    while(table[sentenceToChange])// as long as we are not at the end of the chosen sentence-'\0'
    {
        for(i=sentenceToChange;(lensentence)/2;i++)
        {
                temp=table[sentenceToChange][i];
                table[sentenceToChange][i]=table[sentenceToChange][lensentence-1-i];
                table[sentenceToChange][lensentence-1-i]= temp; 
        }

    }



    }
```

thank you :)

Comment: Funnily enough, I quickly found several SO answers on this topic by using a search engine.

Comment: remove `while(table[sentenceToChange])` or change to `if(lensentence > 1)`

Comment: `for(i=sentenceToChange;(lensentence)/2;i++)` --> `for(i=0; i < lensentence/2;i++)`

Comment: @Tamar Kravitz From your post "I can't use pointers...". However  first function parameter char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH] is already pointer!:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27145672/971127

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that every word ends with a space to *find* every word, then use your reversing code on each of those words.

Comment: o.k., and above all of this should be a for loop that does the revers thing to the whole sentence.. and I'm not sure how to write it

Comment: No, *don't* reverse the whole sentence: reverse each individual word.  Your reversal code should be up to the task, although I'm not clear what you mean by "just changes the order of the chars" -- that's what it is *supposed* to do.

Answer (score 0):

This might help a lil bit :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() 
{
  char name[30] = "Hello";
  strrev(name);  //This will reverse your single word
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I can't use strrev...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge to reverse the words and not the sentence (which is what OP's code does).  Like many problems, break it down in to simpler sub-functions.

1. Call function to change the one sentence of interest.

   ```
   int changeCharOrderInSentence1(char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]);

   int changeCharOrderInSentence(char table[][MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH], 
       int numOfSentences, int sentenceToChange) {
     if (sentenceToChange < numOfSentences) {
       return changeCharOrderInSentence1(table[sentenceToChange]);
     }
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Define `changeCharOrderInSentence1()`

   ```
   void reverse_word(char sentence[], int i, int j);

   int changeCharOrderInSentence1(char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH]) {
     int i=0;
     int count = 0;
     do {
       while (sentence[i] == ' ') i++;
       int j = i;
       while (sentence[j] != ' ' && sentence[j] != 0) j++;
       reverse_word(sentence, i, j);
       i = j;
       count++;
     } while (sentence[i] != 0);
     return count;
   }
   ```
3. Define `reverse_word()`

   ```
   void reverse_word(char sentence[], int i, int j) {
     while (j > i) {
       j--;
       char t = sentence[i];
       sentence[i] = sentence[j];
       sentence[j] = t;
       i++;
     }
   }
   ```

It is not clear what the return value of   `changeCharOrderInSentence()` should be.  This code assumes it is the number of words reversed.

I do not like the name of `MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH` as the name implies the length of a string, yet OP's example uses it like the size of a char array.

Comment: Hi,thank you so much. it's important for me to really understand the code. the code revers_word I understand, but the other 2.. I have no idea what you did in there. can you explain please ?   I don't understand what every variable does and what is for, and what this function number 2 really does.  function 1 also not clear.                                                      do {